# unable to access my wsdl file in my android emulator

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have developed one android application

this is my code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.testprops.com/customerData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.testprops.com";
private static final String URL = "http://87.76.29.180:8080/TestPrompts/services/Fetch?wsdl";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array 

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){ 
        tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
       }
        setContentView(tv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is my local tomcat apache server wsdl file:

```
http://localhost:8089/TestPrompts/services/Fetch?wsdl
```

means it is successfully worked for my emulator and android device.

The same TestPrompts project only i have exported and created war file and uploaded in my tomcat server.

This is my tomcat server wsdl file:

```
http://87.76.29.180:8080/TestPrompts/services/Fetch?wsdl
```

But here only am facing problem:

I have to put these URL means doesn't getting any result on both emulator and android device.Simply am getting black screen only.

console window shows following error:

```
11-19 15:12:55.232: D/SntpClient(73): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

please help me.how can i resolve my error.

Comment: do you have any logcat, any errors?

Comment: no error on my logcat.simply displayed blank screen very long time

Comment: well, debug it and check where the app freezes then.

Comment: i have debug my code.now also am getting same blank screen only.please refer this:http://screencast.com/t/Jbj4tHcug

Comment: ok, 1 questions - does the str variable before splitting has some value. Next, the split method uses Regex for delimiter, you may need to escape the &-character - str.split("\&");

Comment: i have tried this step also.now also getting same blank screen only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some kind of a network issue. Please try to access that wsdl via your browser in you phone or emulator. So you can check weather the connectivity is there.  . Please refer this article. I have done it in my app. http://www.insightforfuture.blogspot.com/search/label/Android

Comment: i have wrote this URL means it is successfully displayed content in my phone and emulator.http://87.76.29.180:8080/TestPrompts/services/Fetch?wsdl      afterthat i have to run the app means the blank screen only displayed.please help me how can i resolve this error.

Comment: i got the solution after gave permission globally for mysql database.